# Serial Communication gets back wrong answer when something is running in the background (like browsing the hard drive)

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-communication

I have some big trouble with serial requests.

Description from what i want:

- establish a serial connection,   send serial requests to 6 temperature
  sensors one by one (this is done every 0,5 second in a loop)
- the question and answer-destination is stored in a List array
- every request is started in a separate thread so the gui does not bug
  while the programme waits for the sensor-hardware to answer

My problem:

The connection and the request is working fine, but if I am browsing data at the local hard drive the answer from the sensor-unit gets destroyed (negative algebraic sign or value from other sensor or simply wrong value). 
How does this happen or how can I solve this?

Where I guess the problem might be:

- In the private void ReceiveThread() of class SerialCommunication

Here is my code:

---

Class CommunicationArray:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hardwarecommunication
{
    public class CommunicationArray
    {
        public string request { get; set; }
        public object myObject { get; set; }
        public string objectType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Class SerialCommunication

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hardwarecommunication
{
    class SerialCommunication
    {
        Thread t2;
        Thread t;
        private SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2", 115200, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);
        string serialAnswer = "";
        private volatile bool _shouldStop;
        private int counter;

        List<CommunicationArray> ar = new List<CommunicationArray>();

        object[] o = new object[3];


        public void addListener(string request, object myObject, string objectType)
        {
            CommunicationArray sa = new CommunicationArray();

            sa.request = request;
            sa.myObject = myObject;
            sa.objectType = objectType;
            ar.Add(sa);
        }

        public void startListen()
        {
            t2 = new Thread(() => writeSerialPortThread());
            t2.Start();
        }



        public void startSerialPort2()
        {

            try
            {
                serialPort.Open();
                //MessageBox.Show("Connection opend!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
        }

        public void stopSerialPort2()
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort.IsOpen == true)
                    // Connection  closed
                    serialPort.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }


        private void writeSerialPortThread()
        {
            string request = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < ar.Count(); i++)
            {
                request = ar[i].request;
                //request = ((object[])ar[0])[0].ToString();
                //if (!t.IsAlive)
                //{
                try
                {
                    t = new Thread(ReceiveThread);
                    _shouldStop = false;
                    //MessageBox.Show("start thread");
                    t.Start();
                    serialPort.Write(request);
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    _shouldStop = true;
                    t.Join();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                Label tmpLabelObject = (Label)ar[i].myObject;
                serialAnswer = serialAnswer.Replace("=", "");
                if (tmpLabelObject.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    MethodInvoker UpdateLabel = delegate
                    {
                        tmpLabelObject.Text = serialAnswer;
                    };
                    try
                    {
                        tmpLabelObject.Invoke(UpdateLabel);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void ReceiveThread()
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("in thread");
            while (!_shouldStop)
            {
                serialAnswer = "";
                try           
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("in thread");
                    serialAnswer = serialPort.ReadTo("\r");
                    if (serialAnswer != "")
                    {
                    }
                    return;
                }
                catch (TimeoutException) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Class Form1 //to establish the connection and to start the Sensor request

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hardwarecommunication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private SerialCommunication serialCommunication1 = new SerialCommunication();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //start up serial connection
            serialCommunication1.startSerialPort2();
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerRecord.Enabled = true;
            if (this.buttonStart.Text == "Start")
                this.buttonStart.Text = "Stop";
            else
                this.buttonStart.Text = "Start";            
        }

        private void timerRecord_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.buttonStart.Text == "Stop")
            {
                this.serialCommunication1.startListen();
            }
        }

        private void buttonFillRequestArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            this.serialCommunication1.addListener("$0BR00\r" + "\r", this.labelResult0, "label0"); //request to the hardware
            this.serialCommunication1.addListener("$0BR01\r" + "\r", this.labelResult1, "label1");
            this.serialCommunication1.addListener("$01R00\r" + "\r", this.labelResult2, "label2");
            this.serialCommunication1.addListener("$01R01\r" + "\r", this.labelResult3, "label3");
            this.serialCommunication1.addListener("$01R02\r" + "\r", this.labelResult4, "label4");          
        }
    }
}
```

---

I woud be happy about any try to fix the problem. 
I coud also upload the solution as .zip but you can't test it at all because you do not have the sensor hardware.

Comment: Your program is probably very sensitive to timing.  Which is what you get when you start adding Thread.Sleep() to your code to make it work.  There's no guarantee that the ReceiveThread() method even calls serialPort.ReadTo(), it will exit immediately when it starts running late.  Swallowing TimeoutException without any diagnostic is also extremely unwise.  Start by removing that thread, it serves no useful purpose other than making your code fail.

Comment: You need to employ a deterministic approach to threading. You have no chance of success with your current approach. Timing cannot be used to control a program.

Comment: Hi, woud be nice to see how this looks like a small example. Thx

Comment: I deleted the "private void ReceiveThread()" and added:                     serialPort.Write(request);
serialAnswer = "";
serialAnswer = serialPort.ReadTo("\r"); into private void writeSerialPortThread() instead of calling the private void ReceiveThread().Tt is working like before with the same bug.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Get a serial port sniffer. I've found this *invaluable* when working with RS-232. I personally use an EZ-Tap Pro (from http://www.stratusengineering.com/EZTap.html, I have no relation to that company). This will allow you to see exactly what is being transmitted across the actual copper, and when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: `serialPort.Write(string)` is a non-blocking store into the output buffer.

That means the following won't guarantee you've even finished writing your request before you stop listening for a response:

```
serialPort.Write(request);
Thread.Sleep(50);
_shouldStop = true;
```

You could add:

```
while( serialPort.BytesToWrite > 0 ) Thread.Sleep(1); // force blocking
```

but it's ill advised.

One thing I'm wondering.  There is only a single serial port here.  Why do you want many different threads to work with it when you could manage the entire serial port interaction with a single thread?  (Or at worse, 1 thread for input 1 thread for output)

To me it makes a lot more sense to store up requests into a queue of some kind and then peel them off one at a time for processing in a single thread.  Responses could be similarly queued up or fired as events back to the caller.

**EDIT:** If you don't mind one read/write cycle at a time you could try:

```
string response;
lock(serialPort) {
    // serialPort.DiscardInBuffer(); // only if garbage in buffer.
    serialPort.Write(request);
    response = serialPort.ReadTo("\r"); // this call will block till \r is read.
                                        // be sure \r ends response (only 1)
}
```

Comment: hi, thx for the answer, I will give it a try tomorrow. I think the problem is not sending the request but getting the answer.

Comment: thx so far but if there is a mistake in the request or a mistake in transmission there wont be a response from the unit. So I need to start a new request after some time and just ignore the first request.   The Process shoud be: write request; read until ("\r"); but if there is no ("\r") within the next 100ms start the next request.

Comment: @kimliv Try: `serialPort.ReadTimeout = 100;` around the time you open the serial port.  (you'll probably catch the exception at some point, there you could optionally `.DiscardInBuffer()`, but only if you remain in the `lock()` will it be a safe operation.)

Comment: one final question @ebyrob. How can I determine if the `serialPort.ReadTimeout` is performed? In this case I woud simply skip the falue.

Comment: @kimliv `.ReadTo()` throws a `TimeoutException` if the `.ReadTimeout` is exceeded.